# A bijection between the semicircle with center (0,1) of radius 1/2 with the set of real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I wanted to build a bijection between the semicircle with center $(0,1)$ of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Projecting the semicircle down to $\Bbb R$ gives you a bijection from the semicircle to the interval $[-1/2, 1/2]$. Do you see where to go from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

A central projetion from the center of the circle can works.

[image]